# Creating struct that is compatible with a priority queue

Tags: c++, struct, operators, priority-queue

I am currently creating a struct in C++ that is compatible with a priority queue (ie I can make a priority queue of Item_Node) and that the priority queue sorts by bound values (higher bound=higher priority). Here is what I have regarding that:

```
struct Item_Node
{
    int level;
    int profit;
    int weight;

float bound (Item_Node u) const
{
    int j,k;
    int totweight;
    float result;

    if(u.weight>=W)
    {return 0;}
    else
    {
        result=u.profit;
        j=u.level+1;
        totweight=u.weight;
        while(j<=n && totweight+w[j]<=W)
        {
            totweight=totweight+w[j];
            result=result+p[j];
            j++;
        }
        k=j;
        if(k<=n)
        {result=result+(W-totweight)*(p[k]/w[k]);}

        return result;
    }
}
}

bool operator<(const Item_Node & ) const;
};

bool Item_Node:: operator<(const Item_Node & right) const
{return bound()< right.bound();}
```

These are the following errors when compiling:
error: new types may not be defined in a return type (on the line of struct Item_Node)
note: (perhaps a semicolon is missing after the definition of ‘Item_Node’)
error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘operator<’ (on the line bool operator< ...)
error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token (on the next line with };)

I especially don't understand the 3rd one because I only have one data type in there to my knowledge.

Comment: As your error says, you're missing a `;` at the end of your `Item_Node` definition.  I can't really tell what all else is wrong, because you haven't given a [mcve].

Comment: The priority queue I am using also is not from the standard library. It is one that uses a binary search tree.